# Apache Ivy: Restrict Publishing to a Repository

Tags: java, apache, ant, ivy

I'd like to have a setup where developers can resolve/retrieve dependencies from a `URL Resolver` (a remote, in-house server hosting our repo) but cannot publish to it (for security and code integrity reasons).

However, for their Ivy clients to "see" the remote repo so they can pull dependencies down off of it, I need to expose the URL in the resolve/retrieve patterns inside our Ant builds. This includes the username & password!

How do I give them "read" (resolution) access, but not "write" (publishing) access?!?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a repository manager like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/), [Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/) or [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/products.php) that has a security model for the repository access. It will allow you to create a read only user for the repository that you give to the developers.

Comment: Are these managers basically middlemen "proxies"? I assume they intercept access/publish requests, compare the username provided by the Ant build against a list of permissions and pass/fail the request? Is this pretty much the gist of it? Otherwise, then the only way they could work would be if they wrapped functionality already existing with Ivy. In which case, I'd rather just tap into that functionality directly, and not deal with the additional overhead of learning a new technology...

Comment: Yes... they are proxy servers for maven and other technologies using code repositories with a whole bunch of advantages like performance improvements, reliability, stability and so on. And they are free to use. There is a saying that friends dont let friends use Maven and other build tools without a repo manager. There is e.g. a free book about Nexus available that explains it all in detail. Disclaimer: I am co author of that book and trainer for Nexus with Sonatype.. and yes you could just "tap into that functionality" and would reinvent yet again what open source repository servers do

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the ant builds that *are* allowed to publish run on servers other than the developers' machines?

In which case, put the username and password into environment variables on those servers and read them using the `environment` option on the [Property](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) task.

Alternatively, read the username and password from a local file.

In any case, keep the credentials local to the machine which should have the permission to publish.